# Install driver by using C++

Tags: c++, installation, driver

This is a question about installing driver.
I have the following files :

aaa.cat
aaa.inf
x86\ttt.sys

I can install this driver by clicking "update driver" in device manager.
But now I need to install this driver on Windows (XP, Vista and Win7) by using C++.
How could I do this?

On the other hand, I can't use install shield or other tool to do the job. That is why I am asking this question.

Thanks in advance.

I have found this page, which mentioned SetupInstallFile  and SetupInstallFileEx  functions.
Is this the answer?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376958%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: "Install this driving by using C++" doesn't have sufficient information

Comment: Sorry, I am installing the driver on Windows.
Is there some other information I need to indicate?

Answer (score 3):

use function `DiInstallDriver` and  `DiInstallDevice`

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa906312.aspx)

Comment: I've been hunting around for a function like this forever. Thank you.